# Sort a list by negative numbers, zeros, then positive Python

Tags: python

How do I make a new list where the numbers are sorted first in negative, then 0's and then positive numbers in Python?

For example if I have the list `a = [3, -5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -2]`
I want the new list to be `[-5, -1, -2, 0, 0, 3, 1]`

Comment: What on earth kind of "sorted" is `[-5, -1, -2, 0, 0, 3, 1]`?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg the numbers retain their original order within the negatives and within the positives. Just all negatives come first, all positives last but not change between themselves.

Comment: @luk2302 Wow OK, the wording of the question is atrocious.

Comment: Yes, fully agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like that

```
b = [x for x in a if x < 0] + [x for x in a if x == 0] + [x for x in a if x > 0]
```

Comment: That actually performs better than a sorting I would assume and is far cleaner since it does not *imply* that anything is being sorted.

Comment: @luk2302 I highly doubt this performs better since you need to allocate 4 different lists

Comment: @mousetail but you scale linearly O(n) - sorting is O(nlogn) in terms of time complexity. Space complexity is worse in this case, yes.

Comment: No, python sorting algorithm is specifically highly optimized if there are lots of equal items and will perform much faster than `O(n log n)`. regardless, allocations are *very* expensive, and even a much worse algorithm will perform better if it saves allocations.

Comment: Did some testing, a.sort is faster for smaller lists, my solution faster for larger lists with > ~ 30 elements -  like luk suggested.

Comment: @bitflip interesting

Comment: Use generator expression and unpacking to avoid unnecessary memory allocations: `[*(x for x in a if x < 0), *(x for x in a if x == 0), *(x for x in a if x > 0)]`

Answer (score 4):

You can set a sort key:

```py
a.sort(key=lambda i:1 if i>0 else 0 if i==0 else -1)
```

You can change this to split by any predicate.

Answer (score 1):

sorting array based on there number and occuerence

```
def func(array):
    dic = {-1:[], 0:[], 1:[]}
    for i in array:
        if i<0:
            dic[-1].append(i)
        elif i==0:
            dic[0].append(i)
        elif i>0:
            dic[1].append(i)
    res = []
    for i in [-1, 0, 1]:
        res.extend(dic[i])
    return res
arr = [3, -5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -2]
sol = func(arr)
print(sol) # [-5, -1, -2, 0, 0, 3, 1]
```